# My eslint is not working in windows with the *.js path argument

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, eslint

I have a node project that is using eslint and it seems to run fine on mac but gives the following command prompt error in a windows machine `'no such file or directory. stat c:\projects\*.js`

It doesn't seem to like the *.js argument.  If I remove *.js and just point to the directory it works fine.  Alternatively, if I explicitly point to a specific file with the full path, that also works.

Here's the lint npm command I'm using

`node_modules/.bin/eslint ./*.js ./**/*.js`

What makes the *.js incompatible on the windows machine?

Comment: what version of eslint are you using? are you using windows command prompt?

Comment: latest eslint, windows command prompt

Comment: Same problem, never found a solution...